# Backbone.js modify newly fetched collection before reset events occur

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Fetch data from the server
2. Add a zero-based index to the models before the views are notified
3. Finally run have the 'render' events fire for the views

I was trying to do this by using a success callback in the collection

**View Before**

```
initialize: () ->
  @collection.on 'reset', @render, this

render: () -> ...render code...
```

**Collection Before**

```
search: () ->
  @fetch { 
    success: @fetch_success
  }  

fetch_success: () ->
  for i in [0...collection.models.length]
    collection.models[i].set('go_index', i)
```

Doing things this way was causing the views to fire their render events before the collection was updated by the success callback.  The solution I came up with was to have the views listen to a `fetched` event, then have the collection fire that after it successfully modifies the collection:

**View After**

```
initialize: () ->
  @collection.on 'fetched', @render, this

render: () -> ...render code...
```

**Collection After**

```
initialize: () ->
  @on 'reset', @add_index_and_notify, this

add_index_and_notify: () ->
  for i in [0...@models.length]
    @models[i].set('go_index', i)
  @trigger('fetched')
```

This works fine, I'm just wondering if this is the most elegant way to accomplish this or if there is a built-in way that I'm missing.

**UPDATE 3/15**

I've come up with a cleaner solution that doesn't require the view to do any of the dirty work and I don't have to create a custom event.  The trick is to listen to the `sync` event (which fires *after* `reset`)

**View Final**

```
initialize: () ->
  @collection.on 'sync', @render, this

render: () -> ...render code...
```

**Collection Final**

```
initialize: () ->
  @on 'reset', @add_index, this

add_index: () ->
  for i in [0...@models.length]
    @models[i].set('go_index', i)
```

Hopefully this pattern can help somebody searching in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already posted the solution in the original question, but I figured I'd formally post as an answer:

The cleaner solution doesn't require the view to do any of the dirty work and doesn't require a custom event.  The trick is to listen to the `sync` event (which fires *after* `reset`)

**View Final**

```
initialize: () ->
  @collection.on 'sync', @render, this

render: () -> ...render code...
```

**Collection Final**

```
initialize: () ->
  @on 'reset', @add_index, this

add_index: () ->
  for i in [0...@models.length]
    @models[i].set('go_index', i)
```

Hopefully this pattern can help somebody searching in the future.

Comment: I have a similar use case, this was helpful. Now I'm just wondering if there are any repercussions in using 'sync' instead of 'reset'.

Answer (score 1):

Your view should get both the model and it's index separately from the collection because the index isn't really part of the model record itself. Try having your view use `collection.each` to loop over the models as the callback function there will get `model, index, collection` as parameters. Remember a view can pass more than just a single model to its template.

```
class CollectionView1 extends Backbone.View
  render: =>
    $el = @$el
    $el.empty()
    @collection.each (model, index) ->
      modelView = new ModelView1 {model, index}
      $el.append modelView.render().el
    return this
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there is no way to tell which view is going to get `reset` first.  The heavy lifting has to be done in the collection so that there is no dependency on the views.  I'll look into overriding parse, too, but I think I came up with a simpler approach

Comment: Huh? That doesn't make sense. Why do you think it matters which view gets the `reset` first? It doesn't. Duplicating collection-specific info (the index) into the model is a bad idea that will eventually prove itself to be more harm than good. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you listen to the **add event** of the collection..

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
  this.listenTo(this.collection , 'add' , this.add_index_and_notify);
  this.index = 0;
},

add_index_and_notify: function(model){
    model.set({go_index : this.index++}, {silent : true});
    // Render the model here
},

render: function(){
   this.$el.empty().append(Your template);
   this.index= 0;
   _.each(this.collection.models, function(model){
         this.add_index_and_notify(model);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but the problem is that there are 2 separate views (a google map and a corresponding list if you're interested) that will use this index.  It seems like this could go in either of those views.  This doesn't seem any cleaner than what I was doing before.  I've come up with a better way - by listening for the 'sync' event that is fired _after_ reset.